# iOS 7 app optimized for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have an iOS 7 app made since more than a year. I want to make it optimized for the new iPhone 6 and 6 Plus screens but want to keep the iOS 7 compatibility. Is it possible ?

I have already made this :
- Add Launch images at the sizes of iPhone 6 and 6 Plus
There are some UI issues, but I can handle them.

My question is : If the iOS Deployment Target and Base SDK are on "iOS 7.0", is it enough to make my app optimized for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus and iOS 7 compatible ?

Comment: You’ll need to add the new icons as well.

Comment: Commonly you just set "Latest SDK" and Deployment target you require.

Comment: Ok ! Thank you guys, so I've to fix the UI issues now. But I can keep my iOS 7 compatibility.

Comment: As Long a the deployment target is iOS 7 and you are nog calling any iOS 8 only API it should be fine. But checking it on both a iOS 7 device and iOS 7 simulator should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the Launch Images are the key to making sure you don't have those black spaces at the top and bottom of your screen. As long as you set your target deployment to 7.0 or 7.1, whichever you prefer, XCode and iTunes Build submission attempts will inform you on and methods or frameworks that are only available to 8.0>